# How to use Layout inflater without onCreateView

Tags: android, layout-inflater

so my code is supposed to support both phone and tablet (tablet with fragments).  I know how to inflate the fragment and set the necessary values in the MessageFragment class but I am supposed to do this in the MessageDetails class instead.  I don't know how to do that.

ChatWindow class has my code that launches based on if I am on the phone or tablet:

```
myDisplay.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(isTablet){
               MessageFragment mFragment = new MessageFragment();

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String idString = String.valueOf(id);
                        bundle.putString("message_id", idString);
                String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatDatabaseHelper.KEY_MESSAGE));
                        bundle.putString("message_value", message);
                        mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.frme,   mFragment).addToBackStack(null) .commit();


            } else { Intent intent = new Intent(ChatWindow.this, MessageDetails.class);
            String idString = String.valueOf(id);

            String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatDatabaseHelper.KEY_MESSAGE));
            intent.putExtra("message_id", idString);
            intent.putExtra("message_value", message);
            startActivity(intent); } //for phone

        }
    });
```

Here is my onCreateView code for the MessageFragment Class:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup       parent, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the xml file for the fragment
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_message_details, parent, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

And Finally, this is my MessageDetails class where I am supposed to inflate the fragment for tablet and assign values (you can see the code for phone layout is already there).

```
 public class MessageDetails extends Activity {
String id;
String message;
MessageFragment mfragment;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_details);




    Bundle bundle;



    TextView delMsg;
    TextView delId;
    Button delBtn;

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    setId(bundle.getString("message_id"));
    setMessage(bundle.getString("message_value"));


    //Missing Fragment Inflater code


    delMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delMsg);
    delId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delId);
    delBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delBtn);


    delMsg.setText(message);
    delId.setText(id);
    delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      Intent intent = new Intent(MessageDetails.this, ChatWindow.class);
                                      intent.putExtra ("delete_id", id);
                                      setResult(RESULT_OK);
                                      startActivityForResult(intent, 33);
                                      finish();


                                  }
                              }

    );


}

public void setId(String delId) {
    delId = id;
}
public void setMessage(String delMessage) {
    delMessage = message;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to embed the fragment based on some business logic, then you can try

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

or, If the `fragment` is already present in your activity's layout xml file, the fragment will be instantiated whenever the `activity's` layout is inflated by the system and the `onCreateView` method of the `fragment` will be called.

As per the official documentation,

> When the system creates this activity layout, it instantiates each fragment specified in the layout and calls the onCreateView() method for each one, to retrieve each fragment's layout. The system inserts the View returned by the fragment directly in place of the  element.

Please follow the official documentation from the below link for better understanding the `Fragment` lifecycle.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Answer (score 0):

Since MessageDetails is an Activity. You can try something like this:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(your_xml_layout)
```